# How to submit multiple values for an object property in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I think a relatively easy question I've had a tough time with grasping in Rails.

How do I get Rails to accept multiple values for an object's property?  And how do I display those items.  Currently, when I try to display, it has blank fields after I create the item.

I'm using Active Admin so the permits looks a bit different below but same concept as would be in a controller.

Here's code (the input form and params are below):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Object do

# See permitted parameters documentation:
# https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
#
permit_params :name, :description, :price, :style_number, :design, :picture, :materials, :country_made_in, collection_colour_id: []
#
# or
#
# permit_params do
#   permitted = [:permitted, :attributes]
#   permitted << :other if params[:action] == 'create' && current_user.admin?
#   permitted
# end

 form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.input :name
    f.input :style_number, required: true
    f.input :design, required: true
    f.input :materials, required: true
    f.input :country_made_in, required: true
    f.input :description
    f.input :collection_colour_id, multiple: true, required: true, :label => 'Colours', :as => :check_boxes, :collection => CollectionColour.all.collect {|u| [u.colour_name, u.id]}
    f.input :collection_colour_id, multiple: true, required: true, :label => 'Colours', :as => :check_boxes, :collection => CollectionColour.all.collect {|u| [u.colour_name, u.id]}
    f.inputs "Upload" do
      f.input :picture, required: true, as: :file
    end
    f.input :price
    f.actions
 end

end
```

The `collection_colour_id` collects from a `collection_colour` model.  Currently when I create a new object, doesn't accept any values for `collection_colour`.  Appreciate any help!

Comment: where is located your `form` ? It should be in a show view. Also: do you create a new item or are you modifiying one. What is the name of the model you are trying to create/modify an item for ?

Comment: I'm using `activeadmin` so it's not in the show view, but the same MVC principles apply really.  I'm creating a new item.  I've edited the code so you can see more details. Hope it helps.